# How to create wifi hotspot in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: hot-spot

I've tried so many things but nothing helped out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Try on the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install kde5-nm-connection-editor`

2. Once installed, press Alt+F2 and run command to launch the app:

`kde-nm-connection-editor`

3. Click Add button and choose “Wireless (shared)” from the drop-down list.
4. Type in a name, ssid, and select Access Point mode. If want, set up a password under Wireless Security tab. Finally, click OK.
5. Click Network Manager applet on Unity panel and then choose “Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi network”, choose the connection you created in previous step and click Connect button.

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/

Comment: For ubuntu **14.04 install kde-nm-connection-editor**, For ubuntu 15.04 install **kde5-nm-connection-editor**